# Channel communication between tasks

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I am trying to set up a channel based communication between one [hyper](https://hyper.rs/) service and one [tokio](https://tokio.rs/) stream. The problem is that the compiler rants with the following error:

> closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `tx_queue` out of
>   its environment.

After reading the explanation provided by `rustc --explain E0525` it appears that [tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.16/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html) implements `Clone` but does not implement `Copy` (unless I overlooked something).

So I am a bit stuck. How can I get my service send messages to a tokio stream via a `tokio::sync::mpsc` channel ? I am sure I miss something obvious but can not see what :/

An excerpt of the problematic code (modified to make it shorter as @E_net4 requested):

```rust
    extern crate hyper;
    extern crate tokio;
    extern crate tokio_signal;

    use futures::Stream;
    use hyper::rt::Future;
    use hyper::service::service_fn_ok;
    use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};

    use futures::sink::Sink;
    use futures::sync::{mpsc, oneshot};
    use futures::{future, stream};

    fn main() {
        let mut runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();

        let (tx1, rx1) = oneshot::channel::<()>();

        let (tx_queue, rx_queue) = mpsc::channel(10);

        // ----

        runtime.spawn(start_queue(rx_queue));

        // ----

        let http_server = Server::bind(&([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000).into()).serve(|| {
            service_fn_ok(move |_: Request<Body>| {
                tx_queue.send(1);
                Response::new(Body::from("Hello World!"))
            })
        });

        let graceful = http_server
            .with_graceful_shutdown(rx1)
            .map_err(|err| eprintln!("server error: {}", err))
            .and_then(|_| {
                dbg!("stopped");
                // TODO: stop order queue listener
                Ok(())
            });

        dbg!("HTTP server listening ...");

        runtime.spawn(graceful);

        // ----

        tx1.send(()).unwrap();

        dbg!("exited");
    }

    pub fn start_queue(rx: mpsc::Receiver<usize>) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
        #[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
        enum Item {
            Value(usize),
            Tick,
            Done,
        }

        let items = rx
            .map(Item::Value)
            .chain(stream::once(Ok(Item::Done)))
            .take_while(|item| future::ok(*item != Item::Done));

        items
            .fold(0, |num, _item| {
                dbg!("x");
                future::ok(num)
            })
            .map(|_| ())
    }
```

The entire code is available here : https://gist.github.com/jeromer/52aa2da43c5c93584c6ee55be68dd04e

Thanks :)

Comment: Please try to make a better [mcve], so that there is everything we need to reproduce the problem is in the question itself. That code snippet alone does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `futures::sync::mpsc::Sender::send` consumes the `Sender` and produces a `Send` object, which is a future that has to be run to completion to actually send the data. If the channel is full, it will block until someone else receives from the channel. Upon completion it gives you back the `Sender` which you could use to send more data in.

In this case I don't think you can structure the code with just single instance of the `Sender`. You need to clone it so that there is new clone for every call of the service function. Notice both closures are `move` now:

```rust
    let http_server = Server::bind(&([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000).into()).serve(move || {
        // This closure has one instance of tx_queue that was moved-in here.
        // Now we make a copy to be moved into the closure below.
        let tx_queue = tx_queue.clone();
        service_fn_ok(move |_: Request<Body>| {
            // This closure has one instance of tx_queue, but it will be called
            // multiple times, so it can not consume it. It must make a copy
            // before consuming it.
            tx_queue.clone().send(111);
            Response::new(Body::from("Hello World!"))
        })
    });
```

But, this would give you following warning:

```
warning: unused `futures::sink::send::Send` that must be used
```

As I said, the `send` just gives you a future that must be run to actually perform the sending. If you ignore the return value, nothing will happen. In this case, it would be best to `spawn` it as a separate task (so it doesn't block responding to the client). To spawn it, you need an executor from the runtime, which also has to be cloned for the inner closure:

```rust
    let executor = runtime.executor();
    let http_server = Server::bind(&([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000).into()).serve(move || {
        let tx_queue = tx_queue.clone();
        let executor = executor.clone();
        service_fn_ok(move |_: Request<Body>| {
            executor.spawn(tx_queue.clone().send(111).map(|_| ()).map_err(|err| {
                // TODO: Handle the error differenty!
                panic!("Error in mpsc {:?}", err);
            }));
            Response::new(Body::from("Hello World!"))
        })
    });
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: damm the error message is non sense. Also the double clone sux a little didn't find why I can't fix the error cause of that

Comment: The cloning looks bad, but it is inevitable. Both of the closures can be called multiple times (they are `Fn`, not `FnOnce`), so they can not give out their own instance of `tx_queue` because they would not have it the next time they are called. So they keep one instance as a template and clone it when called. The clone is then moved/consumed.